Android Studio upgrade
I have an older version of Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 installed on Windows 11 in C:\program files\Android\Android Studio.
I have downloaded the latest Studio version Ladybug 2024.2.1.
When I try to install it, it wants to be installed in the new folder C:\program files\Android\Android Studio 1.
Is this the correct way to update the old version of Android Studio, or should I install the new version into the same folder as the old version ?
Will I still be able to run the old version of Android Studio, if I install the new one into the new folder ?
Will it then be necessary to set up the new Android Studio installation from new, i.e. the old Android studio settings will not be transferred from the old version ?
Please advise the best way to proceed with this update.
Thank you.

Android Studio can not be upgraded (except from the built-in update mechanism). Just uninstall the old version and install the new version. Settings are always stored in your user folder (%APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio<version> which is AFAIK not deleted on uninstall.

Thank you Robert for this advice. I have done it, as suggested.
